# Is there a guide from Arizal concerning the reaction to an insult?

Tags: derech-eretz-manners, arizal

Is there a guide, or some set of guidelines, in Arizal, concerning how to react to insults?

Comment: Is there a reason you want guidelines specifically from the Arizal? Why would other authorities not be adequate for your needs?

Comment: As far as general sources, the *b'raisa* in *Shabbos* (88b) praises those who do not respond to insults, and Rashi's interpretation indicates that this extends to those who rejoice when insulted. See also *Chovos Hal'vavos* (*Sha'ar Yichud HaMa'aseh*, ch. 2), *M'iras Einayim* ([*Eikev*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20635&pgnum=301)), *Magid Meisharim* (*B'shalach*), *Reishis Chochma* (*Anava*, §3), *Sha'arei K'dusha* (Section 4), *Tzava'as HaRivash* (§2), and other sources, who indicate that one should strive to be equally unaffected by praises and insults.

Comment: I am writing a research paper on halachik responses to negative emotional attitudes and wish to include Arizal.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a source from the Arizal however the Shaarei Kedushah intimates that if someone insults you they create an area of de-existence within you which you can compensate for by insulting them back or you can simply wear the hurt.

Although the first option seems halachically permissible if you opt for the second option you emulate God's wearing the universal spiritual hurt created when you do an aveirah and this will stand you in good stead as a recipient of God's largesse towards your shortcomings.